# EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0) (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found this error without any instructions of which part when wrong when showing my tableView.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhmFq.png)

Here's the part of the tableViewCell which might be the problem source:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// Dequeue cell
let cell: UITableViewCell! = self.clientTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClientCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
// Unpack message from Firebase DataSnapshot
let messageSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.messages[indexPath.row]
let message = messageSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
let date = message[Constants.MessageFields.date] as String!
if let imageUrl = message[Constants.MessageFields.imageUrl] {
  if imageUrl.hasPrefix("gs://") {
    FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(imageUrl).dataWithMaxSize(INT64_MAX){ (data, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error downloading: \(error)")
        return
      }
      cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
    }
  } else if let url = NSURL(string:imageUrl), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(data: data)
  }
  cell!.textLabel?.text = "sent by: \(date)"
} else {
  let text = message[Constants.MessageFields.weight] as String!
  cell!.textLabel?.text = date + ": " + text
  cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "ic_account_circle")
  if let photoUrl = message[Constants.MessageFields.photoUrl], url = NSURL(string:photoUrl), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
    cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
  }
}
return cell!
```

}

The whole project is based on a Firebase tutorial, I'm just making a few changes for testing.

Here is the project:
[Github Link](https://github.com/kyujyokei/WaterLog)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minor changes I made in your code allow it to work, and I changed a couple of (imageUrl) to (imageUrl as! String) to keep the compiler happy.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Dequeue cell
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = self.clientTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClientCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    // Unpack message from Firebase DataSnapshot

    // changed vvv
    //print statements are there just to check the data...
    let messageSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    //print(messageSnapshot)
    let message = messageSnapshot.value as! NSDictionary
    //print(message)
    let date = message.objectForKey("date") as! String
    //print(date)
    // changed ^^^

    //old code
    //let message = messageSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
    //let date = message[Constants.MessageFields.date] as String!
    //

    if let imageUrl = message[Constants.MessageFields.imageUrl] {
      if imageUrl.hasPrefix("gs://") {
        FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(imageUrl as! String).dataWithMaxSize(INT64_MAX){ (data, error) in
          if let error = error {
            print("Error downloading: \(error)")
            return
          }
          cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
        }
      } else if let url = NSURL(string:imageUrl as! String), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(data: data)
      }
      cell!.textLabel?.text = "sent by: \(date)"
    } else {

      //let text = message[Constants.MessageFields.weight] as! String! <- doesn't work

        // changed vvv
        let aNum = message.objectForKey("weight") as! NSNumber
        let text = aNum.stringValue
        // changed ^^^

      cell!.textLabel?.text = date + ": " + text
      cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "ic_account_circle")
      if let photoUrl = message[Constants.MessageFields.photoUrl], url = NSURL(string:photoUrl as! String), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
      }
    }
    return cell!
  }
```

Comment: Ah it worked !! Thank you !! I'm super new to Firebase related functions so had no idea how to deal with them. I'll sure study a lot more base on your code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is you try to cast messageSnapshot.value to Dictionary, and it fails.

I suggest you change the line:

```
let message = messageSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
```

to

```
if let message = messageSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
}
```

or

```
if let message = messageSnapshot.value as? [NSObject: AnyObject]{
}
```

and fix compile warning caused by the change.

And you will still find crashes...there is some other bugs in your code...

What's more, you should use "if let", "guard let", optional chaining instead of using "as!", "as String!".

These statement is recommended by Apple. It is safer. It could help you find your bugs more quickly. And it causes less crashes.

Comment: You're right! I was only making modifications from former codes, so there were careless mistakes... Thanks for the advice!